# How to recreate overlay of Polyline in android google map v2 without recreating map surface in fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

An app has a navigation drawer,with fragment containing google map V2 in it. Overlay of Polyline works nicely until device is rotated. Overlay is done through async task. Once the android device is rotated polyline vanished. While recreating the overlay code works but overly are never shown.

Comment: Might want to use another term than `navigation drawer` as that term has it's own meaning in Android and may cause some confusion.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to recreate the overlay?